# trying topolulate the value of textare and input field when i start typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code where i am trying to append the text i write in textarea to my input field, if i delete, it should delete, if i add it should add, i can do a copy/paste and select all things

how can i make sure it works in cases

Here is my jquery code

```
jq('#text').show();
jq("#input1").hide();
jq("#text").focus();
jq('#text').html(jq("#input1").val());
jq('#input1').input(function() {
    var val1 = jq(this).val();
    jq("#text").val(val1);
});
```

my html code

```
<tr valign="middle">
        <td width="200" valign="top"><strong>(*) Question:</strong></td>
        <td><textarea name="question" id="text" style="display:none"> </textarea>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="input1" name="question" value="#form.question#" size="50"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You have hidden the input you have bound the input event too. `jq('#text').input(fun...` and `jq("#input1")..val(val1)`

Comment: so what is wrong i am doing

Comment: I literally just told you! `jq('#input1').input` should be on `jq('#text').input`, and 'jq("#text").val(val1)` should be `jq("#input1").val(val1)`

Comment: that is not working nothing happens

Comment: What Pellay means is that you accidentally switched the IDs of the fields. From your description, the event handler needs to be set on the `<textarea>` and write its value to the `<input>`. Though in your code it's the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .input for jQuery, use just the regular `on` event

https://jsfiddle.net/bradberkobien/dz1rob2p/26/